# Show $y''+\lambda^2y=f(x)$ has root : $y(x)$ satisfying condition : $y(0)=y'(0)=0.$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the equation : $y''+\lambda^2y=f(x)$ has root :  $y(x)$ satisfying condition : $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ and $$y(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{x_0}\sin\lambda(x-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau$$

Answer (score 3):

The boundary conditions imply that, upon Laplace transformation, the above equation is equivalent to

$$(s^2+\lambda^2) \hat{y}(s) = \hat{f}(s)$$

which means that

$$\hat{y}(s) = \hat{f}(s) (s^2+\lambda^2)^{-1}$$

The solution is the inverse transform of this, which is simply the convolution of the inverse transforms of the RHS.  The ILT of $(s^2+\lambda^2)^{-1}$ is $\sin{(\lambda x)}/\lambda$.  Therefore

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^x dt \: \sin{(\lambda (x-t))} f(t)$$